# How does Android Market detect country of the developer's account

Tags: android, google-play

As we know only developers from some countries can publish paid apps on the Android Market.

Could anyone tell how Android Market "knows" or detects the country of the developer?

I don't think it's IP. Simple example - what if I logged in to my developer's account being on vacation?

Maybe it's the country of my credit card which I used to made a Google Checkout payment?
If that's the case what if I have several credit cards from different countries?

Comment: Just pulls it off what is on the google profile I would guess, it needs to be set for other things like google checkout paying.

Comment: Ip adress would be to lame and to strange - what if I logged in to my developer's account being on vacation?

Comment: ok, lets think about this smartly. if you have a cookie set on your browser already, as well as when you made your account this was probably when this was done, to check your ip. Try to go to the dev website while on vaction after clearing your history and cookies and then make a new account, i can guarantee you that you will fall onto the country page that you are in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from my own thoughts and a little research done on this page I it seems that your developer's country depends on the country of a Google Checkout account that you must link to your developer's account to start receiveng payments.

> The Google Checkout account which you need to link to your Android
> Market developer account can only be linked once from within the
> developer account interface.
>
> If you are not located in any of the countries listed above and do not
> own the required bank account for receiving payments, Google may not
> be able to pay for the sales in that account by any other means.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done through a variety of methods, but the easiest, and probably the method utilized, has to do with the country that owns the ip that you appear to be. Although google probably does not need to do this, a simple whois on an ip informs you as to the owner of that ip address. All of the addressable ip blocks have been divied up across different the different internet registries such as Afrinic and arin. Who knows, google may utilize a different method, but this solution is more difficult to spoof than some sort of country flag or other variable that one might pass on the client side.

Comment: Ip adress would be to lame and to strange - what if I logged in to my developer's account being on vacation?

Comment: it depends on where you are on vacation, half the time your computer broadcasts your preference, other times, yes, the ip is used to determine your location, its not lame, its proven. It's more difficult to fake an ip, not impossible, just more difficult. You can think its lame all day long but it is a technique utilized quite often.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't agree with you for many reasons. And the main one is that IP checking doesn't correspond to the reason developers aren't allowed to sell paid apps. Really. You are not banning some troll like it would in case of IP checking or don't filtering traffic from some countries that you can't monetize. You just want to make sure that this particular developer can get their payment.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts though. I'd vote up your answer but it seems a bit wrong for me.